# Give view access permission to DNN module when copying the module from another page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm copying the list of modules from another page in DNN. While doing this I have to set the view permission for all users to view the modules. Even the other page(copying from) module setting is different. Below is the example where I set other properties.

```
ModuleInfo newModule = new ModuleInfo();
0newModule.ModuleDefID = module.ModuleDefID;
newModule.AllTabs = false;
newModule.PortalID = PortalId;
newModule.ContentItemId = module.ContentItemId;
newModule.ModuleTitle = module.ModuleTitle;
newModule.PaneName = module.PaneName;
newModule.TabID = NewTabInfo.TabID;
newModule.ContainerSrc = module.ContainerSrc;
newModule.ModuleOrder = module.ModuleOrder;
newModule.DisplayPrint = module.DisplayPrint;
newModule.DisplayTitle = module.DisplayTitle;
newModule.IsShareable = module.IsShareable;
newModule.IsShareableViewOnly = module.IsShareableViewOnly;
newModule.ModulePermissions=module.ModulePermissions;
newModule.IsWebSlice = module.IsWebSlice;
newModule.WebSliceTitle = module.WebSliceTitle;
newModule.Footer = module.Footer;
newModule.Header = module.Header;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a snippet to dynamically add role permissions to a dotnetnuke module in code behind.

```
//get the current ModuleInfo 
ModuleInfo newModule = ModuleController.Instance.GetModule(ModuleId, TabId, false);
//or create a new module
ModuleInfo newModule = new ModuleInfo();

//clear the old permissions
newModule.ModulePermissions.Clear();

//add admin view permission
ModulePermissionInfo modulePermissionInfo1 = new ModulePermissionInfo();
modulePermissionInfo1.ModuleID = ModuleId;
modulePermissionInfo1.AllowAccess = true;
//view permission id, 1 = view, 2 = edit
modulePermissionInfo1.PermissionID = 1;
//administrator role id (from Roles table in dnn database)
modulePermissionInfo1.RoleID = 0;

//add admin edit permission
ModulePermissionInfo modulePermissionInfo2 = new ModulePermissionInfo();
modulePermissionInfo2.ModuleID = ModuleId;
modulePermissionInfo2.AllowAccess = true;
//view permission id, 1 = view, 2 = edit
modulePermissionInfo2.PermissionID = 2;
//administrator role id (from Roles table in dnn database)
modulePermissionInfo2.RoleID = 0;

//add all users view permission
ModulePermissionInfo modulePermissionInfo3 = new ModulePermissionInfo();
modulePermissionInfo3.ModuleID = ModuleId;
modulePermissionInfo3.AllowAccess = true;
//edit permission id, 1 = view, 2 = edit
modulePermissionInfo3.PermissionID = 1;
//all users role id (from Roles table in dnn database)
modulePermissionInfo3.RoleID = -1;

//add the ModulePermissionInfo to the module
newModule.ModulePermissions.Add(modulePermissionInfo1);
newModule.ModulePermissions.Add(modulePermissionInfo2);
newModule.ModulePermissions.Add(modulePermissionInfo3);

//save the permissions
ModulePermissionController.SaveModulePermissions(newModule);

//clear the dnn cache (if it is the current module, not a new one)
DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearModuleCache(TabId);
DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearTabsCache(PortalId);
DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearPortalCache(PortalId, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps me a lot and I have fixed my issue.