# Copy DNN moduler permission to another DNN module in code

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

[image: Original module permissions]

The code for copy the module looks like below

```
ModuleInfo newModule = new ModuleInfo();
                    newModule.ModuleDefID = module.ModuleDefID;
                    newModule.AllTabs = false;
                    newModule.InheritViewPermissions = true;
                    newModule.PortalID = PortalId;
                    newModule.ContentItemId = module.ContentItemId;
                    newModule.ModuleTitle = module.ModuleTitle;
                    newModule.PaneName = module.PaneName;
                    newModule.TabID = NewTabInfo.TabID;
                    newModule.ModuleOrder = module.ModuleOrder;
                    newModule.DisplayPrint = module.DisplayPrint;
                    newModule.DisplayTitle = module.DisplayTitle;
                    newModule.IsShareable = module.IsShareable;
                    newModule.IsShareableViewOnly = module.IsShareableViewOnly;
                    newModule.ModulePermissions = module.ModulePermissions;
                    newModule.IsWebSlice = module.IsWebSlice;
                    newModule.WebSliceTitle = module.WebSliceTitle;
                    newModule.ContainerSrc = module.ContainerSrc;
                    newModule.Footer = module.Footer;
                    newModule.Header = module.Header;
```

So can some one tell me, Did I miss some thing? Once I copied the module the permission looks like below for newly copied module

[image: This is what I get after copied the module using above code]

Comment: 1 st image is the base module permission. I have to copy the permission from this module to another module in code. But when I did that using above code I got 2nd image look alike permissions

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471977/give-view-access-permission-to-dnn-module-when-copying-the-module-from-another-p. My answer there should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks for the reply. But in this case I can not control the module permission by manually assign it in the code. If the base module has different permission then that should be copy as it is.

Comment: Why manually? Doesn't something like this work? `newModule.ModulePermissions = module.ModulePermissions; ModulePermissionController.SaveModulePermissions(newModule);` (not tested)

Comment: @VDWWD That is working fine. The actual issue was newModule.InheritViewPermissions = true;